# Clean up for queues and connections - console app hangs on exit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Using RabbitMQ in a very simple console app I'm running into a problem where the console app isn't quiting at the end of execution and I *think* it might be because I'm hanging on to something in RabbitMQ. So what exactly do I need to dispose of? I have a class `Queue` class that looks something like this:

```
public class ManagementQueue : IDisposable
{
    private IConnection connection;
    private IModel channel;
    private string privateQueueName;
    private EventingBasicConsumer consumer;

    public event EventHandler SomeEvents;     

    public ManagementQueue()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() 
        { 
            HostName = Properties.Settings.Default.RabbitMQServer,
            UserName = Properties.Settings.Default.RabbitMQUser,
            Password = Properties.Settings.Default.RabbitMQPassword
        };
        connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        channel = connection.CreateModel();

        privateQueueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;        

        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: Properties.Settings.Default.ManagementQueueName,
            durable: true,
            exclusive: false,
            autoDelete: false,
            arguments: null);

      channel.ExchangeDeclare(Properties.Settings.Default.BroadcastExchange, "fanout");       
        channel.ExchangeDeclare(Properties.Settings.Default.DirectExchange, "direct");          

        channel.QueueBind(privateQueueName,
            Properties.Settings.Default.DirectExchange,
            privateQueueName);

        channel.QueueBind(Properties.Settings.Default.ManagementQueueName,
            Properties.Settings.Default.DirectExchange,
            "fromManager");

        channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += ReceivedHandler;

        channel.BasicConsume(queue: privateQueueName, 
            noAck: true, 
            consumer: consumer);
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {
        consumer.Received -= ReceivedHandler;
    }

    private void ReceivedHandler(object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
    {
        // Do some stuff...
    }

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        // send out some message...
        var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        props.ReplyTo = privateQueueName;

        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: Properties.Settings.Default.BroadcastExchange,
                 routingKey: "",
                 basicProperties: props,
                 body: null);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (channel != null)
        {
            channel.Dispose();
            channel = null;
        }
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Dispose();
            connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the console I have something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   if (!args.Any())
   {
       // This works fine exiting here
       return;
   }
   var queue = new ManagementQueue();
   queue.SomeEvents += (o,e) => { // do something };
   queue.StartListening();
   queue.SomeFunction();

   while (!somecondition)
   {
       // do some other stuff
   }
   queue.StopListening();
   queue.Dispose();
   return;    // app should quit here, but doesn't???
}
```

I'm suspicious that it might be something going on with the consumer, but there doesn't appear to be any methods to dispose, close or disconnect it. No where am I explicitly creating any new threads or any tight loops (other than the `while` loop, but that does exit when the condition evaluates to false).

Comment: If it doesn't matter what else is going on when it hits that return, maybe just something more aggressive? `Environment.Exit(0);`, or something to that effect.

Comment: @user1438893: `Environment.Exit(0);` certainly works, but I'd really like to understand what is stopping it from exiting normally so I can make sure everything that needed to be cleaned up gets cleaned up

Comment: If you debug it and stop on the `return` does that `queue` object actually show null? It might be how your `Dispose` function works, I might opt for just saying `queue = null;` instead of `queue.Dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post, but it looks like RabbitMQ has had issues with calling Dispose on IModel.  You may want to just try disposing of the connection and seeing if this resolves the issue.

Ref1: http://markmail.org/message/tqyiezrmixagtwa4#query:+page:1+mid:mhl5iw2gylwznd5o+state:results

Ref2: http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/IModel-Dispose-locks-if-called-during-ConnectionShutdown-event-tc22104.html

Proposed Fix:

> The suggestion is to not call dispose on the IModel instance during the 
>   ConnectionShutdown event.  I had to reword my code to track if it is being 
>   called in a connectionshutdown or not to know when to call dispose.